# How do I clear the cache for a custom block?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I have a custom block which is not updating when the data in the database is updated. It works when cache is cleared.

Is there any solution for this cache issue?

This is the code I am using.

```php
global $base_url;

clearstatcache();
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
$msg='<div id="notice"><ul id="holiday">';
$holiday_select = db_query("select id,student_holiday from student_holiday as b where  b.isactive = 't' and display_from <=now() and display_to>=now() order by id desc");

foreach ($holiday_select as $h_data) {
  $student_holiday[] = $h_data->student_holiday;
}

if (count($id) > 0) {
  $s = 0;
  while ($s<count($id)) {
    $holiday_view = $student_holiday[$s];
    $msg .= '<li><a href="'.$base_url.'/holiday"> ' . $holiday_view . '</a></li>';
    $s++;
  }
}
else {
  $msg .= '<li><a href="#">No holiday </a></li>';
}

$msg .= '</ul></div>';

echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below preprocesser function to your .theme file**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'your_block_ID') {
    // This stops the block being cached.
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have implement in my them  but its not work for me 
`function ngo_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == '29') {
    // This stops the block being cached.
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}`i got 29 as block id while i click my custom block its leads to url as` /block/29`

Comment: already i have try http://purencool.com/how-to-stop-a-specific-block-from-being-cached-in-drupal-8

Comment: Have you tried it in YOURTHEME_preprocess(&$vars) function than in the YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars)? It might work.

Comment: could you pls add some coding i'm using Pixture Reloaded theme as ngo 
so i have added 
`function ngo_preprocess(&$vars){
ngo_preprocess_block(&$vars){
if ($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == '29') {
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
} ` but its not working